# Extension works fine on local system but on live instance it gives me error

Tags: magento2, admin-controller

Can someone please give me some detail about my issue.
I am duplicating categories along with the product on my local system it works fine although it takes little more time but works fine on my live instance it gives me 404 error after completing all functionality don't know why behaving strangely.

My local Magento version is **2.2.7**

live instance Magento version **2.2.7** on which it gives **404 error** and remain stuck on the controller rather than returning value

and

live instance Magento version **2.3** on which it gives me **undefined index** in which I am getting value through post method and it is getting the value I double checked it

Although it completes its functionality in both live instances and then through such error at the end.

Comment: Do you find anything in error logs?

Comment: nothing in error log developer mode is on

Comment: Have you compared your PHP configurations in local and live. What error are you facing in browser console network tab?

Comment: i am using 2.2.7 on local and php 7.0 and on live for 2.3 and 2.2.7 using php 7.1

Comment: Did you run sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile ?

Comment: yes i have done that